# Where do I put "main.js" file in Gatsby project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have a function that grabs an element and adds the class "is-open" in order to toggle an accordion. I have put this function in my "main.js".

In my FAQ component, this function needs to be called when a user clicks the accordion bar.

**My question is: How do I import this main.js file within my Gatsby.js / React project?**

I tried in the index or the component itself. But it is only called once I make changes to the main.js file. Obviously, I want it to be called right away when the page loads up.

This is the function within my main.js file:

```
  const accordionEl = document.getElementsByClassName("faq-module--accordion-title--2zVOe")
  if (accordionEl.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < accordionEl.length; i++) {
      accordionEl[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.parentNode.classList.toggle("is-open")
        const panel = this.nextElementSibling
        if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
          panel.style.maxHeight = null
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = `${panel.scrollHeight}px`
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

Like I said, I have tried to add it like so in my FAQ component:

```
import "../js/main..js"
```

I have also tried to add it in index.html with  tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this in your footer (or some place that always loads):

```
<script src={`path/to/main.js`}></script>
```

*Use the path to the file of the BUILT version. So you should probably put the script in "static/js/", and you should be able to import it from there.*

But this is not really how you want to use Gatsby. Gatsby is built upon React, so for the *reactive* JavaScript, you should really be using React. It can't predict what the state of the DOM is if you start updating it behind its back. Furthermore this should be really easy to recreate in React with a simple onClick handler.